# How to get data from a widget to the model in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am new to flutter. I am working on a simple application where you select a date from the calendar and below you see the information of what happened on that day.

I only have one screen:

- Above is a widget containing a DateRangePicker (https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker).
- Below is another widget called Details, which contains some buttons and a card with the day's information.

I'm currently using provider, but I'm having trouble getting the widgets to communicate with each other. For example, I would like clicking a button on the details widget to cause the calendar widget to send some information to the model's main class.

Is there any way that when activating the button the model calls the calendar so that it extracts the necessary information from it?

As additional information, I have the calendar as a consumer of the main class of the model, because the model modifies the calendar from time to time.

This is my model class:

```
class ShiftSystem extends ChangeNotifier {
  DateTime _currentDay = DateTime(
      DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
  Map<DateTime, Shift>? shifts;
  bool _copyMode = false;
  List<DateTime> selectedDaysToPaste = [];
}
```

This is the calendar:

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Calendar> createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  final DateRangePickerController _controller = DateRangePickerController();
  CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.month;
  TimeOfDay enter = const TimeOfDay(hour: 7, minute: 0);
  TimeOfDay exit = const TimeOfDay(hour: 17, minute: 30);

  @override
  initState() {
    _controller.selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    _controller.selectedDates = [];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ShiftSystem backend = context.watch<ShiftSystem>();
      return SfDateRangePicker(
        onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
          backend.currentDay = _controller.selectedDate!;
          if (backend.copyMode) {
            backend.selectedDaysToPaste = args.value;
          }
        },
        headerStyle: const DateRangePickerHeaderStyle(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
        showNavigationArrow: true,
        monthViewSettings: const DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(
          firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        ),
        selectionMode: backend.copyMode
            ? DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple
            : DateRangePickerSelectionMode.single,
        initialSelectedDates: const <DateTime>[],
        initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
            DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 4)),
            DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3))),
        controller: _controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Changing the day in the calendar updates the value of currentDay in the model. Something similar happens with the selected range of days.

I use both single and multiple mode because I have a "copy mode" so that information can be copied from one day to another.

The widget that contains the provider:

```
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final backend = Provider.of<ShiftSystem>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      //backgroundColor: const Color(0xff23242a),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 65,
        leadingWidth: 75,
        leading:
            IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.settings)),
        elevation: 0,
        //backgroundColor: const Color(0x00ffffff),
      ),
      body: const MainView(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question to show the code you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I couldn't add the code because I didn't find a way to connect the classes. I was looking for tutorials about provider, but in all the cases I see the model is the one that emits the information to the other classes. In my case it is just the opposite: I expect a widget to send information to the model in a particular case.

Comment: Well without providing the code it's impossible for us to help you. Can you still provide the code even if the classes "aren't connecting"

Comment: Ok, I just added the code

Comment: Where in your code are you using `Provider`?

Comment: Oops, i updated the answer again!

Answer (score 0):

To send data back and forth your provider classes you can have a central service or repository class that store this data either in a stream or e.g a ValueNotifier.

From there you can listen to any changes from this providers directly from your service or repository. I don't know if I have answered your question :)

Check my youtube channel where I talk alot about providers [here](https://youtube.com/flutterfairy)